# R: Multiply sign of value Column B by -log10 value Column C

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing 3 columns, "Symbol", "logFC", and "PValue". I would like to create a fourth column labeled "Rank" that takes the sign of the value in "logFC" multiplied by -log10() p value in the "PValue" column. I can do this easily in Excel, but I would like to know if it's possible to do this in R. Thanks.

```
> head(test)
   Symbol  logFC   PValue
1     APP  0.590 0.000156
2   MRPS6 -0.301 0.000307
3 PLEKHA6  2.541 0.000541
4 TSC22D1  0.331 0.000624
5    OMA1  0.268 0.000724
6  POPDC2  0.764 0.000892
```

To create:

```
     Symbol  logFC    PValue  Rank
1       APP  0.590  0.000156  3.8068754016
2     MRPS6 -0.301  0.000307 -3.5128616245
3   PLEKHA6  2.541  0.000541  3.2668027349
4   TSC22D1  0.331  0.000624  3.2048154103
5      OMA1  0.268  0.000724  3.1402614338
6    POPDC2  0.764  0.000892  3.0496351456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test$Rank = -sign(test$logFC) * log(test$PValue, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

By the following command:

```
test$rank <- -1*sign(test$logFC)*log10(test$PValue)
```

or

```
test <- within(test, rank <- -1*sign(logFC)*log10(PValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

```
df <- mutate(df, Rank = sign(logFC) * (-log10(PValue)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, Rank := -1*sign(logFC) * log10(Pvalue)]
```